# ¿Porque dataGridView2.Rows.Add() borra la celda anterior de mi tabla?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Veran, tengo un DataGridView en un Form, el cual, ya tiene celdas y columnas escritas, y quiero que durante la ejecuion del codigo, agregue mas filas a mi DGV, para eso hago:

```
dataGridView2.Rows.Add(cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4);
```

esa linea de codigo no falla, pero yo quiero que agregue una fila nueva,sin sobrescribir la ultima fila del DGV (Porque eso es lo que hace, escribe sobre la ultima fila agregada).

¿como hago para que agregue esos datos sin modificar la tabla? 
Gracias saludos!!!

Comment: como se crean las filas y columnas que del grid ya tiene ?

Comment: Pues inicialmente, los DGV no tienen nada, solo hasta que se manda a llamar el Form que los contiene se agregan las filas y las columnas durante la ejecución del código, mediante la creación de objetos del tipo ´DataGridViewTextBoxColumn´. (Las filas las agrego despues, así como lo describo en la pregunta de arriba...)

Comment: pero todas las rows las agregas usando el Rows.Add() ? o usaste el DataSource

Comment: Solamente usé el Rows.add()

Comment: No uso el DataSource, solamente el Rows.Add();